# Windows batch script - issue with moving files from a directory in a for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have come across an strange issue that puzzles me at the moment -

The windows script I am running is a wrapper script that will loop through all the csv files from a public directory and will move them to a processing folder before I call one of the sub-processes. The wrapper script is supposed to terminate when there is no more csv files left in the input folder. However I am getting a message saying

> 'A duplicate file name exists, or the file
>   cannot be found.'

The input folder \abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa sits as an empty folder with no other files or sub-folders under it.

Any reasons why the following for loop is not terminating normally upon no files and failing instead?

> for /F %%i in ('dir /b "\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa*.csv"') do (

Here is the full code snippet along with the output from the log -

```
***************************************************************************
****    Wrapper Script                                                 ****
***************************************************************************

@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F %%i in ('dir /b "\\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa\*.csv"') do (
   echo Folder is NON empty
        move "\\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa\*.csv" E:\abc\INFILES
    For %%a in (E:\abc\INFILES\*.csv) Do (
        PING 10.1.41.19 -n 5 >NUL
        Set "File=LOADIN.csv"
        Ren "%%a" "!File!"
        CALL "E:\abc\scripts\RUNALL.BAT"
        PING 10.1.41.19 -n 5 >NUL
        MOVE "E:\abc\INFILES\LOADIN.CSV" "E:\abc\INFILES\ARCHIVE\LOADIN - %DATE:/=-% %TIME::=-%.CSV"
    PING 10.2.23.49 -n 3 >NUL
        MOVE "\\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa\OUTPUT\outfile.csv" "\\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa\OUTPUT\ARCHIVE\outfile - %DATE:/=-% %TIME::=-%.CSV"

                             )

        )

EXIT

***********************************************************************
****    LOG OUTPUT                                                 ****
***********************************************************************


Folder is NON empty
\\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa\File1.csv
\\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa\File2.csv
        2 file(s) moved.

RunAll script ran fine.
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) moved.

RunAll script ran fine.
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) moved.

Folder is NON empty
A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.
```

Comment: Your first `move` command moves all the files to the `infiles` folder, but if there were more than one file the `for /f` keeps iterating over the output of the initial `dir` command.

Comment: Thanks @MCND but I have used the entire for loop within a parenthesis. I am wondering if I should use an explicit exit just before I end the parenthesis to come out of the loop when there are no more files to read from the input folder? But if the entire for /f is wrapped within the (), don't understand why would I have to pass an explicit exit?

Comment: If you have ex. 3 files in the folder, the `dir` command will generate three lines of output. The `for /f` iterates over these three lines so the code in the `do` clause is executed three times no matter if you have moved the files and they are not still on the source folder. As you are not using the `%%i` value you can replace the initial `for /f` with just a `dir` and an `&&` conditional execution operator to execute the rest of the code if the `dir` didn't fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command **FOR** executes in a background command process using `cmd.exe` the command line:

```
dir /b "\\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa\*.csv"
```

The output of **DIR** written to handle **STDOUT** is captured by **FOR**. A possible error message output by **DIR** on no *.csv file in specified directory is redirected to console of command process running **FOR**.

Command **FOR** processes line by line the captured output after the background command process finished with execution of **DIR**.

For that reason it does not matter what happens next with the *.csv files in the specified directory. **FOR** has already the list of file names to process line by line in memory.

This commented batch code could be better for your task:

```
@echo off
if not exist "\\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa\*.csv" (
    echo Folder "\\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa" contains no CSV files.
    goto :EOF
)

echo Folder "\\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa" contains CSV files.
set "File=LOADIN.csv"

rem Move all CSV files from \\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa to E:\abc\INFILES.
move /Y "\\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa\*.csv" E:\abc\INFILES\ >nul

rem Process each CSV file in E:\abc\INFILES using subroutine ProcessFile.
for %%I in (E:\abc\INFILES\*.csv) do call :ProcessFile "%%I"

rem Exit processing of this batch file.
goto :EOF

:ProcessFile
rem Wait 4 seconds if a device with IP address 10.1.41.19 exists.
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 10.1.41.19 -n 5 >nul

rem Rename the current file temporarily.
ren %1 "%File%"

rem Call another batch file doing something.
call "E:\abc\scripts\RUNALL.BAT"

rem Wait again 4 seconds if a device with IP address 10.1.41.19 exists.
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 10.1.41.19 -n 5 >nul

rem Move the temporary file to input archive folder with
rem regional settings dependent date and time in new file name.
move "E:\abc\INFILES\%File%" "E:\abc\INFILES\ARCHIVE\LOADIN - %DATE:/=-% %TIME::=-%.CSV"

rem Wait again 2 seconds if a device with IP address 10.1.41.19 exists.
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 10.2.23.49 -n 3 >nul

rem Move output CSV file to output archive folder again with
rem regional settings dependent date and time in new file name.
move "\\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa\OUTPUT\outfile.csv" "\\abcinc.lcl\utility\aaa\OUTPUT\ARCHIVE\outfile - %DATE:/=-% %TIME::=-%.CSV"

rem Exit the subroutine ProcessFile.
goto :EOF
```

The usage of a subroutine makes it possible to process all CSV files without usage of delayed expansion.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `ping /?`
- `set /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Mofi for the detailed explanation and for your time and effort rewriting the routine. Much appreciated. I am reading through the commands help pages and theres a bunch of information on how each of them gets processed by cmd.exe in the background. Thanks again!!